# Creating a attachment from Google sheet in ms Excel format via Google script

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, email-attachments

Is it possible to create an Excel format file from a Google sheet using Google script, so that it can be added as an attachment to an email?

I've got a code that takes columns with certain names (e.g. A, C, F) and turns them into a new sheet (on createCustomStatusTable() function).
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fZ0JMYjoIrfPIxFBVgDNU0x5X0ll201ZCU-lcaTwwcI/edit?usp=sharing

```
var expected = ['A','C','F'];
var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var tableLastRow = newSpreadSheet.getLastRow();
var tablelastColumn = newSpreadSheet.getLastColumn();
var values = newSpreadSheet.getRange(1, 1, tableLastRow, tablelastColumn).getValues();
var rangeToCopy = [];

function in_array(value, array) 
{
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
    {
        if(array[i] == value) return true;
    }
    return false;; 
};
function columnsCount() {
  var count = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn(); i++) {
    if (in_array(values[0][i],expected)) 
       count++;
  }
    return count;
};
function returnRange() {
  for (var i = 1; i < SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn()+1; i++) {
    if (in_array(values[0][i-1],expected)) {
      rangeToCopy.push(newSpreadSheet.getRange(1, i, newSpreadSheet.getMaxRows()));
    };      
  };
  return rangeToCopy;
};

function createCustomStatusTable() { 
 var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Target');
 for (var i = 1; i < columnsCount(); i++) {
       returnRange()[i-1].copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(1,i));
  }; 
};
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can create an EXCEL type file with DriveApp:

[image: DriveApp Excel Type]

The problem is, that the `content` must be a string.  And I haven't tested for a way to make that work.

I know this doesn't answer your question.  Hopefully someone knows for sure how to create an EXCEL file from a Google Sheet.

Comment: I need smth like this [link](https://gist.github.com/ixhd/3660885), but in Excel format .xlsx. Is it possible?